# C# deserialization of JSON string with different property names

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm having trouble deserializing a JSON string in C# to an object whose property names slightly differ from those in the JSON string. Here is my code:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class AuctionFilesList
{
    [JsonProperty("files")]
    public List<AuctionFile> Files { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class AuctionFile
{
    #region Properties
    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("lastModified")]
    public long LastModified { get; set; }
    #endregion
}

string jsonResponse = "{\"files\":[{\"url\":\"http://auction-
api.com/auctions.json\",\"lastModified\":1495397839000}]}"

AuctionFilesList auctionFiles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuctionFilesList>(jsonResponse);
```

I get no errors, it just fails to deserialize into the object. I have tried adding serializer settings as follows but it still fails:

```cs
JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
AuctionFilesList auctionFiles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuctionFilesList>(jsonResponse, jss);
```

My class structures agree with what json2csharp returns and it works when I match the property names of the object to the JSON, so either I am misunderstanding what JsonProperty does or it is being ignored somehow.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code works without any modification on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GTo5SY). Are you sure your object is not deserialized?

Comment: The Files property of auctionFiles is set to null after deserialization.

Comment: The object was deserialized correctly and you can access the `auctionFiles.Files[0].Url` and get `http://auction-api.com/auctions.json` based on @Federico Dipuma 's fiddle.

Comment: Strange. Doesn't work the same when I run in visual studio.